# Firebase Crashlytics doesn't show changes in Dashboard/Console iOS app

Tags: ios, firebase, crashlytics

I've been following [an official doc from Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/upgrade-sdk?platform=ios) and [this tutorial on Medium](https://medium.com/@paulsoham/firebase-crashlytics-in-ios-swift-1d8c9aec63d0) to double-check.
I am sure I have:

- downloaded `GoogleService-Info.plist`
- added it to the root of my project
- in my `Podfile` replaced Fabric and Crashlytics with

```
pod 'Firebase/Crashlytics'
pod 'Firebase/Analytics'
```

- made `pod install`
- added a run script in Build Phases

```
${PODS_ROOT}/FirebaseCrashlytics/run
```

- added input files

```
${DWARF_DSYM_FOLDER_PATH}/${DWARF_DSYM_FILE_NAME}/Contents/Resources/DWARF/${TARGET_NAME}
$(SRCROOT)/$(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)/$(INFOPLIST_PATH)
```

- changed `Debug Information Format`to `DWARF with dSYM File`
- imported `import Firebase` in `AppDelegate.swift`
- added

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    FirebaseApp.configure()
    return true
}
```

- crashed an app
- log

```
 [Firebase/Crashlytics] Version 7.0.0
```

**My problem is that this keeps running and that's it.**

What am I doing wrong and how can I upgrade to FirebaseCrashlytics correctly? Thank you!

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that you're simulating a crash with the debugger still attached, so Crashlytics can't catch it, hence why you have nothing in your dashboard.

To properly test your implementation locally, follow these steps:

> - Click `Build and then run the current scheme` (the play button) in Xcode to build your app on a device or simulator.
> - Click `Stop running the scheme or action` (the stop button) in Xcode to close the initial instance of your app. This initial instance
>   includes a debugger that interferes with Crashlytics.
> - Open your app again from the simulator or device.
> - Force a crash in your app.
> - Open your app once more to let the Crashlytics API report the crash. Your crash should show up in the Firebase console within 5
>   minutes

Source: https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/force-a-crash

Comment: hi and thank you a lot for saving my day! This finally worked, hurray!